# how to compare to vector statement in R

Tags: r

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RNjZ.png)

Please help me with the issue.

below is the example

```
Statement         comment
good boy          positive feedback
good student      positive feedback
good employee     positive feedback
good boy          negative feedback
good student      negative feedback
good employee     positive feedback
```

in the above table we have 6 statement and we do have duplicates. Now want to know the those statements which are same and different comments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unique` function.

```
#Sample data
 df <- data.frame(Statement  = rep(c("good boy", "good student",
                                  "good employee"), 3), 
                 Comment  = rep(c("positive feedback", "negative feedback",
                                    "neutral feedback"), 3))

df

      Statement           Comment
1      good boy positive feedback
2  good student negative feedback
3 good employee  neutral feedback
4      good boy positive feedback
5  good student negative feedback
6 good employee  neutral feedback
7      good boy positive feedback
8  good student negative feedback
9 good employee  neutral feedback
```

Using `unique` function

```
unique(df)
```

Output:

```
      Statement           Comment
1      good boy positive feedback
2  good student negative feedback
3 good employee  neutral feedback
```

## Edit.

In that case I would the `tidyvese` package/approach.

```
require(tidyverse)

#Creating new sample data
df <- data.frame(Statement = c("good boy", "good student",
                               "good employee", "good boy", "good student",
                               "good employee"), 
                 Comment = c("positive feedback", "positive feedback",
                             "positive feedback", 
                             "negative feedback", "negative feedback", 
                             "positive feedback"))
```

Notice that your main problem is that you didn't numbered your comments. I arranged them by statement and numbered them by alphabetical order.

```
df %>%
  #First arrange by statment
  arrange(Statement, Comment) %>% 
  #Group by statment and give unique IDs
  group_by(Statement) %>% 
  mutate(CommentNumber = seq_along(Comment)) %>% 
  #Spread by CommnetNumber (your new "ID") and Comment
  spread(CommentNumber, Comment)
```

final results:

```
Statement     `1`               `2`              
  <fct>         <fct>             <fct>            
1 good boy      positive feedback negative feedback
2 good employee positive feedback positive feedback
3 good student  positive feedback negative feedback
```

Comment: Hi DJV,

Thank you for your time and answer.
need both first comment and the second comment in the output that too side by side. Please let me know if there is any approach for this. Once again thanks for your answer.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please give me an example output?. Please note, that I used my own sample data, and not yours. And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to arrange (i.e. sort) your dataframe (let's call it `df`), then you could for example do:

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(df, Statement, Comment)
```

in order to sort your dataframe by `Statement` and then by `Comment`.